# New to JS, Can't Fix Errors With School Project

Tags: javascript

I'm working on a project for a computers class, and am new to JavaScript. I keep getting NaN for output, and have looked for answers and haven't found any. (Project is a compound interest calculator and UI design is done.)

I'm not really sure what to try, cause I'm a JS newbie.

```
var i = getNumber("amountInput");
var c = getNumber("compoundedInput");
var l = getNumber("lengthInput");
var r = getNumber("rateInput");
var rc = r / c;
var cl = c * l;

onEvent("calculateButton", "click", function() {

  var rca = 1 + rc;
  var p = Math.pow(rca, cl);
  var f = i * p;
  setText("outputArea", f);

});
```

Output should be a number, but I am getting NaN.

Comment: What does `getNumber()` do?  I suspect that's part of the problem.

Comment: It takes a number from an input. Is there anything else that might do the same thing?

Comment: Post the implementation of the getNumber() method

Comment: Well as Barmar says you'll need to do that *inside* the "click" handler; those initial assignments do not create a permanent binding between the variables and the `<input>` fields.

Comment: I got it worked out thanks for your input though.

Answer (score 1):

You need to set all the variables inside the `onEvent` function, so that you get the values of the inputs after the user clicks the button. You're setting them when the page is first loaded, and the inputs will be empty at that time.

```js
onEvent("calculateButton", "click", function() {
  var i = getNumber("amountInput");
  var c = getNumber("compoundedInput");
  var l = getNumber("lengthInput");
  var r = getNumber("rateInput");
  var rc = r / c;
  var cl = c * l;
  var rca = 1 + rc;
  var p = Math.pow(rca, cl);
  var f = i * p;
  setText("outputArea", f);

});
```

Answer (score 0):

`NaN` in JS means 'not a number'. [(mdn reference)](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/NaN)

Usually, you would see `NaN` when you're trying to convert a non-numeric string to a number, either explicitly (e.g. `parseFloat('3')`), or implicitly (e.g. the expression `3 * 'a'` will implicitly try to convert 'a' to a number). Worth noting, dividing by zero does not give `NaN` in JS (it gives `infinity` or `-infinity`); however, `0/0` also gives `NaN`.

For your use case, you're expecting `getNumber` to return a numeric, but it seems like it isn't. Look at your `getNumber` code (or copy it in your question).

Answer (score 0):

if you want to get number from input in html you cant use `getNumber()`

```
<input type="text" id="number" >
<button id="submit">Submit</button>
```

and for geting the number:

```
const number = documnet.getElementById('number');
const submitBtn = document.getElementById('submit');

submitBtn.addEventListener('click', () => {
    const plusOne = 1 + Number(number.value);
    console.log(plusOne)
});
```